# Is power low for a high speed fan?

Tags: power, fan, torque

Got a question for my lab telling that the power consumed is low at higher speeds, why is it so? couldn't find any source backing up this statement too

[image]

I did find this graph of torque vs speed, so I am guessing then its because lesser Torque is required at higher speeds, which then raises the question why is the graph the way it is?

I am guessing breakaway torque is increasing the power required at lower rpms which is why some of the graph at higher rpm has lesser power.